# ¿Cómo mostrar un tipo dato date en formato '0000-00-00' cuando viene vacío?

Tags: php, html

Tengo que traer muchas fechas y algunas se encuentran vacías con el formato '0000-00-00' en mi base de datos, y a la hora de realizar la consulta SQL me las muestra de esta manera: '31-01--0001' y lo ideal seria poder mostrarlo de esta manera: '00-00-0000'.

Dejo mi fragmento de código acá:

```php
<?php
    $query = $conn->prepare("SELECT calendariorecambiocolchones.idCalendarioRecambioColchones, calendariorecambiocolchones.seDistNave, naves.nombre,
    calendariorecambiocolchones.observacionGeneral, inforecambiocolchones.cambioColchon, inforecambiocolchones.revisionColchon,
    inforecambiocolchones.recepcionColchon, inforecambiocolchones.entregaColchon, inforecambiocolchones.ultimaCompra, calendariorecambiocolchones.fechaEmision 
    FROM calendariorecambiocolchones
    JOIN inforecambiocolchones ON calendariorecambiocolchones.idCalendarioRecambioColchones = inforecambiocolchones.idCalendarioRecambioColchones
    JOIN naves ON naves.seDistNave = calendariorecambiocolchones.seDistNave
    GROUP BY calendariorecambiocolchones.idCalendarioRecambioColchones
    ORDER BY inforecambiocolchones.ultimaCompra ASC");
    
    $query->execute();
    $result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    foreach($result as $row){

        $idCalendarioRecambioColchones = $row['idCalendarioRecambioColchones'];
        $fechaEmision = $row['fechaEmision'];                      
        $seDistNave = $row['seDistNave'];
        $naveNombre = $row['nombre'];
        $ultimaCompra = $row['ultimaCompra'];
        $recepcionColchon =$row['recepcionColchon'];
        $entregaColchon =$row['entregaColchon'];
        $revisionColchon =$row['revisionColchon'];
        $cambioColchon =$row['cambioColchon'];
        $observacionGeneral = $row['observacionGeneral']; 

?>
<tr>
    <td class="small"><?php echo $naveNombre?></td>
    <td class="small"><?php echo date("d-m-Y", strtotime($fechaEmision))?></td>
    <td class="small"><?php echo date("d-m-Y", strtotime($ultimaCompra))?></td>
    <td class="small"><?php echo date("d-m-Y", strtotime($recepcionColchon))?></td>
    <td class="small"><?php echo date("d-m-Y", strtotime($entregaColchon))?></td>
    <td class="small"><?php echo date("d-m-Y", strtotime($revisionColchon))?></td>
    <td class="small"><?php echo date("d-m-Y", strtotime($cambioColchon))?></td>
    <td class="small"><?php echo $observacionGeneral?></td>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema está en la función [`strtotime()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.strtotime.php). Cuando pasas una fecha incorrecta como lo es "0000-00-00" a esta función te va a devolver "-62150025600", que al pasárselo a `date()` te lo convierte en "30-11--0001".

Si lo quieres en una sola línea podrías hacer algo así:

```
echo ($fechaEmision == "0000-00-00") ? "00-00-0000" : date("d-m-Y", strtotime($fechaEmision));
```

O por el contrario podrías hacerlo en varias líneas fuera del HTML:

```php
if ($fechaEmision == "0000-00-00") {
    $fechaEmisionConvertida = "00-00-0000";
} else {
    $fechaEmisionConvertida = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($fechaEmision));
}
?>
<tr>
  <td class="small"><?php echo $naveNombre?></td>
  <td class="small"><?php echo $fechaEmisionConvertida?></td>
```

Answer (score 1):

Otra forma de hacerlo sería desde la misma instrucción SQL. Así evitarías tener que manipular los datos nuevamente a posteriori.

Asumiendo que usas MySQL, esto se haría combinando [`DATE_FORMAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) con [`COALESCE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce). Si usas otro SGBD, sólo cambia el código por sus funciones equivalentes.

Como podrás ver en los enlaces al Manual de Referencia, `DATE_FORMAT` te permite dar un formato cualquiera a una fecha, usando marcadores muy parecidos a los que se usan en PHP y en casi todos los lenguajes, y con `COALESCE` cambias los nulos por el valor que quieras. Luego sólo tienes que imprimir el valor de cada columna sin más manipulaciones de los datos.

También, para clarificar un poco el código, he usado [`sprintf()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.sprintf.php), evitando por una parte la creación de variables para cada columna y la mezcla de bloques PHP / HTML que crean un código confuso. Con `sprintf` creamos una especie de plantilla (en la variable `$td`) y luego sustituimos el marcador `%s` por el valor de cada columna, concatenando todo en una variable `$html` que podrás mostrar al final.

El código quedaría así:

```
<?php
    $sql="SELECT 
        calendariorecambiocolchones.idCalendarioRecambioColchones, 
        calendariorecambiocolchones.seDistNave, 
        naves.nombre,
        calendariorecambiocolchones.observacionGeneral, 
        COALESCE(DATE_FORMAT(calendariorecambiocolchones.fechaEmision, '%d-%m-%Y'),'00-00-0000') AS fechaEmision,
        COALESCE(DATE_FORMAT(inforecambiocolchones.ultimaCompra, '%d-%m-%Y'),'00-00-0000') AS ultimaCompra,
        COALESCE(DATE_FORMAT(inforecambiocolchones.recepcionColchon, '%d-%m-%Y'),'00-00-0000') AS recepcionColchon,
        COALESCE(DATE_FORMAT(inforecambiocolchones.entregaColchon, '%d-%m-%Y'),'00-00-0000') AS entregaColchon,
        COALESCE(DATE_FORMAT(inforecambiocolchones.revisionColchon, '%d-%m-%Y'),'00-00-0000') AS revisionColchon,
        COALESCE(DATE_FORMAT(inforecambiocolchones.cambioColchon, '%d-%m-%Y'),'00-00-0000') AS cambioColchon,       
    FROM calendariorecambiocolchones
    JOIN inforecambiocolchones ON calendariorecambiocolchones.idCalendarioRecambioColchones = inforecambiocolchones.idCalendarioRecambioColchones
    JOIN naves ON naves.seDistNave = calendariorecambiocolchones.seDistNave
    GROUP BY calendariorecambiocolchones.idCalendarioRecambioColchones
    ORDER BY inforecambiocolchones.ultimaCompra ASC";
    
    $query = $conn->prepare($sql);
    
    $query->execute();
    $result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $td='<td class="small">%s</td>';
    $html="";
    /*
        No agrego las columnas idCalendarioRecambioColchones y seDistNave 
        porque no aparece en tus td 
        puedes agregarlas siguiendo el mismo modelo de las líneas 
        $html.= ..., siempre después de la apertura de <tr> y antes de </tr>
    */
        
    foreach($result as $row){
        $html.='<tr>';
        $html.=sprintf($td,$row['nombre']);
        $html.=sprintf($td,$row['fechaEmision']);
        $html.=sprintf($td,$row['ultimaCompra']);
        $html.=sprintf($td,$row['recepcionColchon']);
        $html.=sprintf($td,$row['entregaColchon']);
        $html.=sprintf($td,$row['revisionColchon']);
        $html.=sprintf($td,$row['cambioColchon']);
        $html.=sprintf($td,$row['observacionGeneral']);
        $html.='</tr>';
    }
    /*
        En $html vas a tener concatenadas tus filas 
        puedes hacer un echo $html o concatenarla
        con más contenido
    */
?>
```